# How Can I push Notification from my android app using by Nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, notifications, push, onesignal

I m developing an android application ,it is almost done, just  I wanna push notification from my app using by nodejs with ONE Signal service ,I use nodejs and mongodb from backend my app. I connected one signal and android studio each other I have  server api key , project number and app id but I dont know how to use in nodejs Can u help me thnks all of you.

Try to something in here with nodejs code:

```
var GCM = require('node-gcm-ccs');
var gcm = GCM('771515397729', 'bff09b26-ecde-446d-a8ff-0b83f23edeab');

app.post('/sendnotification',function(req,res){

        var message = req.body.message;
        var registrationId = req.body.registrationId;

        sendFunction.sendMessage(message,registrationId,function(result){

            res.json(result);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

/* need express, body-parser,express,fcm-push...other modules */

try this function  ->

```
function sendNotification(tokenToSend, menssage) {
    var serverKey = 'APYKEY';
    var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

    var message = {
        to: tokenToSend, // required
        collapse_key: '', 
        data: {},
        notification: {
            title: 'Push Notification Server',
            body: menssage,
            icon: "ic_launcher",
            sound: "default",
            color: "#00BCD4"
        }
    };

    fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something has gone in your message wrong!");
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thnk you for your response but  Ihave simple question more, Do I need to create schema for that code like notificationschema ?